# Why do I have partly no code syntax highlighting in Komodo-edit?

Tags: python, komodo

I use Komodo-edit to edit usually python files, and so far the syntax highlighting works fine.

But currently I have created two files in the same(!) session which are in different tabs: `test2.py` and `test3.py`. In one case the code is syntax highlighted, for the other code it is not. Everything is just in black font colour.

What is going on? How to have syntax highlighting for this tab?

When I right-click in a tab I can select `Properties and Settings` which opens a new window. In this window, I select `File Preferences` -> `Languages` -> `Syntax Checking`. In there the selected language is `text` and I cannot change it. The section is called `Language-specific syntax checking properties`.

Answer (score 0):

In the `Properties and Settings` just go to `File Preferences`. Here you can change the language setting.